# How do I get this subclass method to override this superclass method?

Tags: java

How do I get this subclass method to override the superclass method?

```
/** Base class */
abstract public class TableGui<T extends DbTable<R>, R extends DbRow> {

    protected void launchAddDialog(AddDialog<R> dialog) {
        dialog.show();
    }

    static abstract class TableGuiDialog<R extends DbRow> {
    }

    static public class AddDialog<R extends DbRow> extends TableGuiDialog<R> {
    }
}

/** subclass */
public class EqTableGui extends TableGui<EqTable, Eq> {

    protected void launchAddDialog(AddDialog<R> dialog) {
        // Do other things 
    }
}
```

In the subclass, I either say:

```
    @Override
    protected void launchAddDialog(AddDialog<R> dialog) {
        dialog.show();
    }
```

And I get "The method launchAddDialog(TableGui.AddDialog) of type EqTableGui must override or implement a supertype method"...

Or I remove the `@Override`, and get "Name clash: The method launchAddDialog(TableGui.AddDialog) of type EqTableGui has the same erasure as launchAddDialog(TableGui.AddDialog) of type TableGui but does not override it"

Comment: What is `R` within `EqTableGui`?

Comment: Please provide an actual [mcve]. There's some important bits missing here.

Comment: Since `EqTableGui` extends `TableGui<EqTable, Eq>`, which is defined as `TableGui<T extends DbTable<R>, R extends DbRow>`, that means that `R` is `Eq`, so method should be `protected void launchAddDialog(AddDialog<Eq> dialog)`.

Comment: In your subclass you specify `R` to be `Eq`, so ẁhat about `@Override
    protected void launchAddDialog(AddDialog<Eq> dialog) {`

Comment: Why are you writing a subclass that does the exact same thing as the superclass? Instead, you should just declare a variable.

Comment: @Andreas, That worked.  I have to learn about it.  I would like to do more than `dialog.show()`.  In this case, I'm just providing an example. Thx. @Biffen, there is no `R` in `EqTableGui`.

Comment: @CollinD, I may have missed something by having had this problem, but no, this example has what it needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be:

```
@Override
protected void launchAddDialog(AddDialog<Eq> dialog) {
        dialog.show();
}
```

The R type parameter is assigned to Eq.

Comment: Thanks.  That's new to me.